# Session access through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, session

I did a web application in Java. It requires to manipulate a session variable through JavaScript. How to do it? Can access through `<%= %>` this notation but how to set it back?

Comment: I guess you're going to have to do an XMLHttpWebRequest...

Comment: you should give a bit more details if you want precise help - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a XHR which POSTs to a .jsp or servlet which manipulates the session value.

i.e. POST /changeSessionValue.jsp

```
<%
session.setAttribute("mySessionValue", request.getParameter("mySessionValue"));
%>
```